# How I write If and else functions in selenium webdriver

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write the selenium webdriver script but i don't  no How I write If and else functions in selenium webdriver.

Comment: Spend 60 seconds googling your own question and find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("*********")).isDisplayed())
         {
               // Click on Teaching Notes
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);     
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("****")).click();     

          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          Thread.sleep(4000);  

         System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("***")).getText());
                    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
                    driver.navigate().back();
                    driver.navigate().back();

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("No Teaching Notes Present");
                    driver.navigate().back();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use general syntax of language you are using in your script.
  for instance if you choose to use java in your script-
    if(condition)
    {
        //body
    } 
    else
    {
        //body
    }